# why XMLHttpRequest too slow with my codes?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

i code some simple form and decided to use XMLHttp Request to submit data to a php file but its seems is slow compared to using php. Is there anything i can do to make this fast. I'm getting mad at it because i have to hit the submit button like 3 times  before the page moves to the next page

```
xmlr.open('POST', 'form/i.php');
    
    
    var fnam = document.getElementById('firstname-input').value;
   
    
    
    xmlr.onload = function () {
      if (this.status === 200) {
       
        
        function movON() {
            
 
            
          window.location.href = "features.php"
          
          
    
        }
         setTimeout(movON, 1000); 
        
        
      } else {
        console.log('error');
      }
    }
    
    xmlr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");
    xmlr.send('&fxnam=' + encodeURIComponent(fnam) )
```

Comment: do you know what `setTimeout(movON, 1000);` does? also, perhaps there's an error - have you tried an onerror handler? also, check the browser developer tools network page - perhaps the server is taking a long time respond - in which case, the fault is probably with your PHP code

Comment: yh i know what it is,  1000 milliseconds isn't that much to make the page load like 200s

Comment: `200s` ... sounds like the server code is doing something wrong, keeping the connection open for that long - so, the problem is in PHP (no surprise)